# Tap method on UIButton when its a sub view of UIView not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uibutton, subview

I'm getting an EXC_BAD_ACCESS error when I tap the UIButton. If I move the logic to the `RootViewController.m` it works, but not when implemented in my `PanelViewController.m`. I can't understand why this wouldn't work, what am I missing and how can I get this to work?

RootViewController.m

```
#import "RootViewController.h"
#import "PanelViewController.h"

@interface ListViewRootController ()

@end

@implementation ListViewRootController
    - (void)viewDidLoad {
        [super viewDidLoad];

        [self.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height)];
        [self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];

        PanelViewController *panelView = [[PanelViewController alloc] init];

        [self.view addSubview:panelView.view];
    }
@end
```

PanelViewController.m

```
#import "PanelViewController.h"

@interface PanelViewController ()

@end

@implementation PanelViewController
    - (void)viewDidLoad {
        [super viewDidLoad];

        UIView *topBar = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 60)];
        topBar.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

        UIButton *mapButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, topBar.frame.size.height)];
        [mapButton setTitle:@"Map" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [mapButton setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [mapButton addTarget:self action:@selector(mapViewToggle:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];

        [self.view addSubview:topBar];
        [topBar addSubview:mapButton];
    }

    - (void)mapViewToggle:(UIButton *)sender{
         NSLog(@"hello, is it me youre looking for");
    }
@end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes, it won't work, panelView controller is released after this

```
PanelViewController *panelView = [[PanelViewController alloc] init];
```

You should have a var in .h of RootViewController, somethings like

```
@interface RootViewController : UIViewController {
  PanelViewController *panelView;
}
```

then:

```
     panelView = [[PanelViewController alloc] init];

     [self.view addSubview:panelView.view];
```

Comment: Thank you! That makes complete sense. I have now fixed it and its now working as expected :)